# Spring @RequestBody json deserialization - Unsupported Media type

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am getting the famous Json deserialization exception with spring 4.1.0.RELEASE:

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Only that after pouring through several similar threads, I am still not able to find the cause of the issue

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public  @ResponseBody String myMethod( @RequestBody MyObj request) {

    .....
}
```

POJO:

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Integer something;  
Integer[] somethingElse;

// Getters and setters
```

}

I do have the jackson dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

in my POM

I issue the following request:

{
   "something" : 4,
   "somethingElse": [1,2]
}

I checked that I have a properly formatted JSON and its hitting the appropriate controller on my server.

Now what could be going wrong????

EDIT: 
This change in the config fixed the problem:

In my root config

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="application" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" value="json" />
                <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean> 
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
```

In servlet config

```
<mvc:annotation-driven> 
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">       
       <beans:ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"></beans:ref>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

In POM, add latest versions of
jackson-mapper-asl,
jackson-core,
jackson-databind,
jackson-annotations

Thanks everyone

Comment: if you can show your bookTables() then that would be helpful...

Comment: have you used <mvc:annotation-driven/> annotation in your xml configuration file or @EnableWebMvc annotation?

Comment: @ Prasad Its actually just a stub right now. The exception is thrown before the controller method is executed.

Comment: @ Code_Cracker Ive used the <annotation-driven/> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you disabled the default MessageConverter? It seems that in your config the MappingJackson2MessageConverter is missing.

Can you provide your mvc config?

Comment: @Wlademar .. thanks so much. I was indeed missing the MappingJackson2MessageConverter. Adding it in my mvc config fixed the issue