# Spring 5.0.0 MockMvc: Unsupported media type, even with correct MediaType set

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

I am using JUnit4 with Spring Web MVC Test and I have test class for a Controller.

The Controller handles a POST request to "/test" with JSON body content. I've tested this method manually using Postman and I get a 400 Bad Request response, as expected, since the "name" property is empty.

```java
POST /Server/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "name": ""
}
```

However, when I send the same request to my Controller through my test class, I get a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) error, even though the request is the same.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyControllerTest {

@Configuration
public static class MyControllerTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyController myController() {
        return new MyController();
    }
}

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnBadRequest_IfBodyIsEmpty() throws Exception {
    // Works fine
    mockMvc.perform(post("/test"))
           .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnBadRequest_IfInvalidFields() throws Exception {

    MyDTO dto = new MyDTO();
    dto.setName("");

    // Jackson object mapper
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // TEST FAIL: Gets 415 error
    mockMvc.perform(
                post("/test")
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(dto))
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            )
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

And here's MyController.

```java
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void init(@javax.validation.Valid @RequestBody MyDTO dto) {
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void validationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    }
}
```

And here's MyDTO.

```java
@lombok.Data
public class MyDTO {
    private String name;
}
```

I have Jackson in my dependencies as well.

Here's what the test class's request looks like when it's printed to the console:

```java
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /test
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
             Body = {"name":""}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = controller.MyController
           Method = public void controller.MyController.init(dto.MyDTO)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 415
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Accept=[application/octet-stream, text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, */*]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Anyways, why would I be getting this error? The request looks perfectly fine to me. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me whether test will return 415 if you omit `.characterEncoding("UTF-8")` ?

Comment: @AlehMaksimovich Yeah, it still does.

Comment: It is suspicious that `MockHttpServletResponse` `Headers = {Accept=[application/octet-stream, ...]}` doesn't contain `application/json`. Maybe you don't have a Jackson or other Spring supported JSON library on your test classpath (runtime dependency?).

Spring will look specifically for a HttpMessageConverter assoicated to the mime type to perform the conversion. Spring boot configures MappingJackson2MessageConverter automatically if jackson is on class path.

Comment: @AlehMaksimovich Well, `ObjectMapper` is an object from the Jackson databind package and it is present in `MyControllerTest.java`, and the test runs without compilation errors. Would that mean it's in the classpath?

Comment: This post may contain a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978022/spring-requestbody-json-deserialization-unsupported-media-type/25981444 I believe you have `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` not registered but with the information in your question I can't say why.

Comment: In your test class's request, Why Request URI is /api/admin/init, my understand is it should be /Server/test, isn't it?

Comment: @AmitKBist My bad. That is the URI in my files, but I've changed it to /test in this context to make it detached from my project. Thanks for pointing it out. (To prevent misunderstandings, this does not mean the problem was solved.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved the issue by annotating my MyControllerTestConfiguration inner static class with @EnableWebMvc.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc // <------------ added this
    public static class MyControllerTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public SetupController setupController() {
            return new MyController();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I had a `@SpringBootTest` annotated class, and adding `@EnableWebMvc` to either the main controller (a `@RestController` to be specific) or the config was out of the question. I tried different approaches and none worked, probably because we had some dependencies that overrode some Spring versions on the POM, and changing that was also not possible. Based on the duck wizard's answer, I came up with a specific test configuration class:

```java
@TestConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ControllerTestConfig {
   @Bean
   public SetupController setupController(SetupService setupService) {
       return new SetupController(setupService);
   }
}
```

And the controller test class went like this (approximately):

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoconfigureMockMvc
@Import({SecurityConfig.class, ControllerTestConfig.class})
public class ControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    //...

}
```